# Whose `git` is it anyway?

Tags: posix, sh

A Posix function for finding the nearest parent file. For example "what .git/ am I working in?" or "is there an .npmrc affecting `npm` from this path?"
This implementation specifically follows the symbolic links toward root rather than the canonical path.

Looking for improvements and potential edge cases.

```sh
lsup() {
  path="$1";
  file="$2";
  if [ -z "${file}" ]; then
    file="${path}";
    path="$(pwd)";
  fi;
  path="$(realpath -es "${path}")"
  [ -n "${SH_DEBUG}" ] && echo "Searching for ${file} from ${path}…";
  while [ "${path}" != "/" ]; do
    [ -e "${path}/${file}" ] && break;
    [ -n "${SH_DEBUG}" ] && echo "Not found in ${path}";
    path="$(realpath -s "${path}/..")";
  done;
  [ -e "${path}/${file}" ] && echo "${path}/${file}" || return 1;
}
```

[https://gist.github.com/psaxton/6937fec3357f8295828d2e3577f9bcb6](https://gist.github.com/psaxton/6937fec3357f8295828d2e3577f9bcb6/0ab2f05d49ac3fd638f4d756513ebb02dc92981d)

Used as:

`> lsup .git`

`> lsup /path/to/check .npmrc`

Comment: The variables should probably be decared `local` if your shell supports that, or else changed to have more specific names which are less likely to clash with user variables with the same names. E.g. `_lsup_path` and `_lsup_file` would be quite a lot uglier, but correspondingly safer if you don't have `local`.

Comment: `realpath` is not in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) (detailed link: [utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html) section). https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101080/realpath-command-not-found suggests `readlink -f`

Answer (score 3):

First, dump all those empty statements (`;` followed immediately by newline).

It might be better to swap the order of arguments, so the optional one is last:

```
file=$1
path=$(realpath -es "${2:-$PWD}") || return 1
```

(No need for quotes for RHS of assignment; explicit fail instead of depending on `set -e`).

The conditional printing gives an error return when `$SH_DEBUG` is unset; turn it around so that the pipeline is always true.  Expand as `${SH_DEBUG-}` so that this works when `set -u -e`.  Log output should go to standard error stream, not output.

Since we have an absolute path and we're not expanding symlinks, we can use a simple pattern substitution in the iteration, rather than :

```
path=${path%/*}
```

We could turn the loop around, so that it terminates when the file is found, instead of repeating the test.

---

## Modified code

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu  # will work with any combination of these flags

lsup() {
    file=${1:-}
    [ "$file" ] || return 1
    path=$(realpath -es "${2:-$PWD}") || return 1

    [ -z "${SH_DEBUG-}" ] || echo >&2 "Searching for ${file} from ${path}…"

    until [ -e "${path}/${file}" ]
    do
        [ -z "${SH_DEBUG-}" ] || echo >&2 "Not found in ${path}/"
        [ -n "$path" ] || return 1
        path=${path%/*}
    done
    echo "${path}/${file}"
}
```

Comment: Very nice review. Thank you for taking the time. I appreciate the simplicity that changing the argument order yields, but feel awkward taking a filename before a path. Your comments regarding variable expansion were enlightening. I will keep those points in mind in the future. Changing to an `until` loop is really the icing on the cake I was hoping for but just couldn't produce on my own. Cheers.

Comment: Also as a small nit if `realpath` is given `.` it can only come up with the canonical path. `$(pwd)` or `$PWD` must be used to use the current path if its the child of a symlink.

Comment: Good point - I've updated to use `$PWD` as the default.  This variable is specified by POSIX, so it's portable.  `$(pwd)` can be slower, and may yield the canonical path if not provided as a shell built-in.  (To demonstrate, move into a directory via symlink and compare results of `pwd` and `/bin/pwd`).